# C# Winforms How to update toolStrip in function

Tags: c#, winforms, visible, toolstrip

I'm building a UI for a program, and I can't figure out why my progress bar won't become visible after the convert button is clicked.

```
private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripProgressBar.Visible = true;

    ...

    toolStripProgressBar.Visible = false;
}
```

I ran into a similar problem with tkinter in Python, and I had to call a function to update the idle tasks. Is there a way to do this with windows forms without using threads?

Edit: On a side note, this is a progress bar in a toolStrip that also contains a label that gets updated with status bar text. Is there any way to get the label on the left side and the progress bar on the other instead of right next to each other on the left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there *is* a way to do this without using threads (`Application.DoEvents`) but I *strongly* recommend against you using it. Re-entrancy is nasty, and you really don't want the UI thread tied up at all.

Use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead - it's easy, and it's pretty much *designed* for progress bars. It takes the hassle out of using a separate thread and reporting progress back to the UI thread. No need for `Control.Invoke` etc - it takes care of that for you.

There are [lots of tutorials for `BackgroundWorker`](http://www.google.com/search?q=backgroundworker%2Btutorial) - it shouldn't take you too long to get going with it.

Comment: I assume you recommend moving the long running process to a separate thread, to keep the UI usable at all times correct?

Comment: Yes - that's what BackgroundWorker makes easy.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I was hoping to avoid threads since they're pretty difficult manually and this is a simple UI, but this sounds perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Per the question you asked for the way to do this WITHOUT threads, that is to do it with Application.DoEvents();.  (Just add that call right after setting the progress bar as visible.)

Now I do agree with Jon Skeet though that BackgroundWorker is a better way of doing this, but it does use a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your process in a thread separate from the UI thread, and then have it periodically report back to the UI thread with it's progress.  If your convert operation is working inside the UI thread, it will simply go unresponsive until the operation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is that the `"..."` in your code is a long-running process.  UI updates are not instantaneous, but must run through the message queue in windows and then be painted to the screen.  The queue is pumped and painting takes place in the same thread as your events.

As a result, any long-running tasks need to be moved to a different thread.  More than that, your line line of code needs to called after that thread terminates.  Otherwise you set the progress bar and then immediately turn it off again.

One way to do that is with a BackgroundWorker control.

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar can only become visible when it is allowed to paint which occurs during the processing of messages.  Message processing cannot normally happen while you are in the middle of an event handler.  If you want the progress bar to show up you will have to set the visiblitity to true, start a background thread to complete the work and return from the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here go two links trying to explain you how things work:
[(1)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/begininvoke.aspx?display=Print) [(2)](http://davebrooks.wordpress.com/2007/02/12/begininvoke-the-land-of-confusion/)

Now, I will try to explain it as shortly as I can. Most of what happens inside a windows forms application happens in a single thread, usually the same thread Main() runs in. If you open Program.cs, you will see that Main() has a line that looks like the following:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

If you debug the application at any moment and examine the call stack, you will see it will trace back to that Run method. This means that a Windows Forms application is in fact a continuous run of the Run method. So, what is Run doing? Run is eating a message queue through which Windows sends messages to it. Run then dispatches those messages to the correct controls, which themselves do things like add text which corresponds to the key being pressed, redraw themselves, etc. Notice that all this happens during and endless loop running alongside a single thread, so weather you are typing or simply moving the window around, loads of those messages are being passed onto the application, which in turn is processing them and reacting accordingly, all in that single thread. Controls can also send messages to themselves through the queue and even you can place messages in the pump via Control.BeginInvoke. One of the things those controls do is to raise events according to what happens. So, if you click a button, the code you've written to handle that click will ultimately and indirectly be run by the Application.Run method.

Now, what is happening with your code is that even though you are changing the visible status of your progress bar to visible and then updating its Value, you are then changing its visibility to false, all in the same method. This means that only after you leave the method, will Application.Run() be able to continue iterating and consuming the message queue, effectively asking the progress bar to update its display. When that happens, you've already left the progress bar's visibility to false, the last thing you did before exiting the method. DoEvents() is a quick and dirty workaround to your problem as it reads the messages in the queue and processes them. I don't really feel comfortable using it as it can bring reentrancy problems.

Using threads is a good solution, but I would recommend using a ThreadPool thread instead of a custom thread in this kind of situation, as I tend to use custom threads only in cases where I have a limited number of long lived threads and I need to control their life cycles. The easiest and most practical way to use threads is to use the BackgroundWorker component, even though I would recommend going through the pains of understanding how to do Windows Forms multithreading with delegates if you want to really understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. The BackgroundWorker solution worked, and I'll look into delegates in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to call refresh on the status strip.
I believe this causes the UI thread to repaint the status strip.

```
toolStripStatusBar1.PerformStep();
statusStrip1.Refresh();
```

This is for .NET 4.0.  Even though this question is old it was the first I found on googling this issue.